# Angular 4 - Http request error: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, http, typescript, rxjs

While trying to do a HTTP Post request I am receiving the following error:

> auth.service.ts?c694:156 Something went wrong requesting a new
>   password, error message: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was
>   expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

The Http request is preceded by another one, which works perfectly fine.

My component calling the service:

```
requestNewPassword(formInput: NgForm) {
     if(formInput.controls['email'].value != '')
      this.authService.getApplicationAccessToken()
      .mergeMap((response: IAuthAppResponse) => this.authService.requestNewPassword(formInput, response.access_token))
      .subscribe(response => {
        // Content removed for simplicity
      })
    }
```

The service method throwing the error:

```
public requestNewPassword(formData: NgForm, applicationAccessToken: string): Observable<any> {
      let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization':'Bearer ' + applicationAccessToken
      });
      let email: string = formData.controls['email'].value;
      const body = {
        email: email
      };

      console.log('requestNewPassword call header: ' + headers.get('Authorization'));
      console.log('Email: ' + body.email);

      return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/api/user/password/forgot', body, {headers}).do(response => {
        console.log("New password was successfully sent to the e-mail adress");
      }).catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log('Something went wrong requesting a new password, error message: ' + error.message);
        return Observable.throw(error);
      })
    }
```

Whenever I enter an email in the form and submit, which in turn triggers the requestNewPassword method of the component, I receive the error mentioned above from the service.

The header and email are logged correctly so I don't think there's anything with the data I am providing.

Since I have no idea how to debug this, I thought it was a good idea to post this as a question on this incredible platform.

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I minimized the code in my component to narrow down the problem by not chaining the two HTTP requests but only call the second one, that is causing trouble.

```
requestNewPassword(formInput: NgForm) {
      if(formInput.controls['email'].value != '')
      this.authService.requestNewPassword(formInput, "")
       .subscribe(response => {
         // Content removed for simplicity
       })
     }
```

I now get a full stack trace:

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js?c011:74)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js?e2a2:132)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js?e2a2:129)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js?e2a2:112)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js?215e:89)
    at ScalarObservable._subscribe (ScalarObservable.js?d097:49)
    at ScalarObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js?4e06:172)
    at ScalarObservable.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js?4e06:160)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js?e2a2:87)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js?4e06:157)
    at FilterOperator.call (filter.js?35ab:60)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js?4e06:157)
    at MapOperator.call (map.js?c4af:56)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js?4e06:157)
    at DoOperator.call (tap.js?7fa8:63)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js?4e06:157)
    at CatchOperator.call (catchError.js?0867:79)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js?4e06:157)
    at PasswordResetComponent.requestNewPassword (passwordReset.component.ts?c169:43)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (PasswordResetComponent.html:7)
    at handleEvent (core.js?223c:13255)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js?223c:14740)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js?223c:14327)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js?223c:9704)
    at eval (core.js?223c:12028)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js?223c:4235)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js?215e:238)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js?215e:185)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js?215e:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js?215e:89)
    at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.js?c1c6:55)
    at EventEmitter.emit (core.js?223c:4203)
    at NgForm.onSubmit (forms.js?ad57:5710)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (PasswordResetComponent.html:7)
    at handleEvent (core.js?223c:13255)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js?223c:14740)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js?223c:14327)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js?223c:9704)
    at eval (core.js?223c:10318)
    at HTMLFormElement.eval (platform-browser.js?023b:2614)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?fad3:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js?223c:4620)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?fad3:424)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js?fad3:192)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js?fad3:499)
    at invokeTask (zone.js?fad3:1540)
    at HTMLFormElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js?fad3:1566)
```

Since this mentions the html, I will provide the html code aswell:

```
<form class="custom_form" #requestNewPasswordForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="requestNewPassword(requestNewPasswordForm)">
    <label>E-mail</label>
    <input class="custom_input" type="email" class="inputfield form-control" ngModel name="email">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
      Send
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: When asking about an error, always post the exact and complete stack trace of the error. It tells **where** the problem is.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: What is the status of the HttpErrorResponse? This seems like an error message coming from your server.

Comment: Whenever I try to log the status it just returns undefined

Comment: I don't think it's a server error because it works with postman.

Comment: where do you try to log the status?

Comment: I updated the question with a way better stack trace

Comment: the mergeMap needs return

Comment: @ChauTran look at the updated information, I now only subscribe and don't use mergeMap since I'm only doing one request to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Try getting rid of the do/catch operators and just return the post?

Comment: The code you posted seems like it should work. Is there anything you left out of the `this.http.post...`? Are you importing all the correct rxjs operators?

Comment: @ChauTran That results in the same error

Comment: @LLai It looks like I have all of the necessary imports.

Comment: The error is stating that the string `'undefined'` is getting passed in as a property. Are any of your values the string undefined? If not I would recommend to keep simplifying your solution until you find the issue. All the way down to a basic post request with static inputs.

Comment: I changed my code so that the service uses static data, but the error remains. However it seems to come from the html on the form opening tag. Any ideas?

Comment: try {headers: headers} instead of what you currently having: {headers}?

Comment: @ChauTran tried it, but didn't make a difference. I don't think it is the service that is giving the errors though. The stack trace complains about the html.

Comment: `at PasswordResetComponent.requestNewPassword (passwordReset.component.ts?c169:43)` what line is this?

Comment: @ChauTran it's the line with  ".subscribe(response => {"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the problem lies in how you construct your Observable. I'd use a debugger if you have one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161456/discussion-between-chau-tran-and-dennisn).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After a lot a lot of effort, I have managed to locate and fix the problem.
The problem was that I have an authorization interceptor that is intercepting every request to add an Authorization header with a user access token.

Since the call I was trying to do didn't require a user access token, but an application access token (authenticate as application for public Http requests like register, forgot password etc.), I decided to chain the call to get the application access token and the call for the forgotten password and just pass the retrieved application access token to the forgotten password method in my service and set it in the Authorization header there. This code was all fine. The problem was that I had edited the interceptor to check wether there was an Authorization header present and if so do nothing and THAT was the cause of the bug.

Instead of doing nothing, I should have just returned the request, so it just gets executed without modifications to the header.

so instead of

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if(request.headers.get('Authorization') == null) {
          //Code to add Authorization header
          return next.handle(requestWithAuthHeader)
        }
}
```

I had to do the following:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if(request.headers.get('Authorization') == null) {
          //Code to add Authorization header
          return next.handle(requestWithAuthHeader)
        } else {
          return next.handle(request);
        }
}
```

Otherwise the request gets intercepted and never executes because it doesn't get returned by the interceptor. 
The method in my component is subscribed to the result of the service method and thus expects an observable, but nothing ever gets returned because the request got intercepted and the interceptor noticed that an Authorization header was already present (set in the service) so decided to do nothing with the request.

This explains why I got the error stating that I had provided undefined while a stream (observable) was expected on the subscribe line in my component's method.

Comment: Thank you, I had a problem similar to yours and your solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue. It also ended up being a problem with an HTTP interceptor. I had an automatic deserialization function running on all responses with a particular API endpoint pattern. Responses which weren't instances of `HTTPResponse` ended up being eaten. Adding an else statement which returned the response untouched when not an instance of `HTTPResponse` solve the issue for me:

```
@Injectable()
export class DeserializerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).map(
      event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          let response = event as HttpResponse<any>;
          // ... deserialization of response object
          return response;
        } else {
          return event; // ... adding this else statement fixed the `undefined` error.
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

(Removed error handling code, for clarity.)