# Angular app being able to access json file under assets folder in Microsoft Azure

Tags: json, angular, typescript, azure, observable

Currently i have an angular 9 app which is able to access config.json file placed under assets folder.I have config service which is responsible for reading from this file. This works with no issues when i run locallly. The file path is /dist/assets/config.json.

However when i deploy this app on azure as Azure App Service (windows OS) strangely the app cannot find this config.json file even though i can clearly see the file is under assets folder. Below are the relevant code from each file. The code fails when the config service tries to grab the file config.json with an error message

```
Error occured while grabbing config files
config.service.ts:65 TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide 
an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27)
at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:53)
at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:36)
at MergeMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:3)
at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
at MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:21)
```

appmodule.ts

```
 function configFactory(configService: ConfigService) {
    return () => configService.loadConfig();
 }     

 providers: [
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  deps: [ConfigService],
  multi: true,
  useFactory: configFactory
},
```

ConfigService.ts

```
 loadConfig() {
    return this.http.get<Config>("assets/config.json").subscribe(x=>{
        console.log("Successfully grabbed config files");
        this.config=x;
    },error=>{
        console.log("Error in grabbing config files");
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
    <!-- this is so that app can find json file when deployed in azure -->
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
 </system.webServer>
```

angular.json

```
          "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/web.config"
        ],
```

I also referred to this link [Angular app unable to find asset files on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56213819/angular-app-unable-to-find-asset-files-on-azure) but the solution proposed there doesnt work in my case. I have also set  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true in my tsconfig.app.json file.

Comment: the error you pasted above doesn't appear in local?

Comment: @AakashGarg It doesnt give any errors. It can access the file without any issue.

Comment: You project is able to load images from assets folder?

Comment: @AakashGarg there is no image in the assets folder. All i have is config.json file there. There is one file favicon.io and it is at the root folder (directly under wwwroot folder) i can see that file being loaded without any issue

Comment: the url getting formed for accessing that json is correct? you check network tab?

Comment: what is the project name in your azure?

Comment: @AakashGarg  surprisingly in the network tab i dont see any information about config.json. i can see the one for favicon.ico though

Comment: @AakashGarg Project name is unrc-willis-web

Comment: you build using command ?

Comment: @AakashGarg yes its typical ng build

Comment: answer is below for your help

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng build --prod --base-href /unrc-willis-web/

Or Try

ng build --prod --base-href "./"

**Also interceptor had issues. interceptor was getting used for a non required call**

Comment: Build failed as it doesnt like the second parameter. I think what we need to find out is to somehow find a relative path to that location.

Comment: yes, and remove --prod from it. Might be your code is not aot compatible. Refer https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/tips-for-running-an-angular-app-in-iis/

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred: Project './' does not support the 'build' target.

Comment: Please note i am using AzureDevops build and the code  repository is in Git

Comment: can you try accessing your json directly in your browser from azure url?

Comment: Yes i can access it and see the file contents as well via the url.

Comment: is it same as it hits from angular?

Comment: when the angular app runs i dont see any url accessing the json file in the network tab. I have a feeling the way i have defined the path here is not correct. this.http.get<Config>("assets/config.json")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214564/discussion-between-aakash-garg-and-sike12).

Comment: @Sike12, if it worked for you. please vote my answer. and refere to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869196/angular-4-http-request-error-you-provided-undefined-where-a-stream-was-expe how to modify your interceptor for not adding authorization header to assets request.

Comment: Sorry @Aakash. My PC crashed and had to restart everything. Let me know if you can make for another zoom meeting sometime later in future. For now i'll accept your answer. Thank you for your time today.

Comment: we can have it now?